# Can not start service

Tags: windows-services

When I try to start an application service it shows error 997 overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Is this a service you wrote. If not maybe superuser.com is a better place to pose your question

Answer (score 0):

When you run the Active Directory Installation Wizard (Dcpromo.exe), if you promote a member server to a domain controller, the operation fails, and you may receive the following error message:

> Overlapped I/O operation is in
>   progress.

**CAUSE**

This problem can occur if a third-party, real-time backup product is installed on the server. The third-party service interferes with the Active Directory Installation Wizard when it recreates the SYSVOL folder.

**RESOLUTION**

To resolve this problem, remove the third-party backup software, restart the server, and then run the Active Directory Installation Wizard again.

**STATUS**

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products that are listed at the beginning of this article.

Found that [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295712) by use of [google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: This Error can happen on a varaity of reasons, I have deleted the existing DSN connection & added again , and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This Error can happen on a varaity of reasons, I have deleted the existing DSN connection & added again , and it worked

Comment: You may want to mark this as the answer then.